# How to clean old sticky pc mouse with rubber coating?

Tags: cleaning, technology, hardware

I have an old Logitech MX510 mouse which is very sticky on the sides. How can I get rid of this stickiness?

Answer (score 4):

Isopropyl alcohol works really well. (99,9%). I just used an old t-shirt as cleaning cloth. Completely removes the rubber coating. No more sticking and there is no way it can come back! 
If for any reason you want to have back the rubber coating you can apply [Plastidip](https://plastidip.com/).

I also successfully used this method on my 3D Connexion Space Navigator 3D mouse.

Comment: Dose anyone know if I can use ethanol as well? Dose it have the effect as isopropyl?

Answer (score 1):

Newer model Logitech mice like MX Master 3 resist 91% iso without losing all the rubber, so you can get a decent, if imperfect, cleaning done with 91% and a paper towel.

I do wish they would just dump the rubbery coating found on so many mice.  It's such a germ and grime magnet.